# How do you view quarantined mailbox on Microsoft Exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange-2010, spam

When certain emails are quarantined for high spam scores, exchange sends a default email to the recipient stating that the email was quarantined for x reason. How do you view the quarantined emails? I have postmaster@domain.com set as the quarantined mailbox, but I can't view any of the emails that are quarantined.

Setup:

We use Mcafee SASS(?) cloud spam protection, however that is not what is catching these emails. If an email is quarantined by Mcafee the user is send a spam digest at the end of the day with options to release, delete, or view the quarantined messages - this works fine.

On exchange under Organization, Hub Transport, Anti-Spam, Content Filtering.
I have it set to quarantine messages with SCL rating greater than or equal to 9.
The Quarantine email address is set to Postmaster@Domain.com
And then I have my exceptions, custom words, etc.

This is what is received by the user who's message has been quarantined, which I can't find to release.

```
> The message or an attachment did not reach the intended recipient(s).!
> Subject: RE: private
>     From: blah@blah.com
>       To: user@localdomain.com
>     Date: --datestamp--   Reason: content policy violation   Action: quarantine
```

Comment: Do you use Forefront ?

Comment: No I dont use forefront.

Comment: Maybe you have an anti-spam (appliance/software) in front of your Exhange servers ? (here i am trying to understand why you cannot see quarantined emails in your dedicated mailbox)

Comment: Yes sass mcaffee protection but what im referring to is the exchange server itselfs anti-spam control.

Comment: @user2196728 He's talking about the Exchange mail quarantine.  It's actually a thing, yeah.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Yes i got that, but the fact is that he actually cannot view quarantined emails in his dedicated mailbox. I was wondering if there were some anti-spam appliance on the way that could quarantined emails before they reach the dedicated Exchange mailbox...seems there is (maybe). In my infrastructure this is the way things works.

Comment: @Jeff You generally use an Outlook client or OWA (Outlook Web Access) to view email in a mailbox, not the Exchange Management Console on the Exchange server.  Is that, maybe, your problem?

Comment: @HopelessN00b no, that is where I am confused. I figured I could use OWA to view the quarantined messages and then maybe release them, but the inbox for postmaster@domain is empty.

Comment: @user2196728 I confirmed just to make sure I wasn't over looking. I can view emails that were quarantined on the cloud level through mcafee easily. Whenever an email is quarantined through the mcafee software the user is emailed an end of day 'digest' of quarantined emails which gives them links to view, release, or delete the messages that were caught. This message comes from the exchange server itself from hub transport -> anti-spam -> content filtering. The quarantined mailbox e-mail address is postmaster@kranichs.com, but nothing gets send to that mailbox.

Comment: Updated the question to provide more information.